# error in basic flutter widget rendered in VS code

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter

I am new to flutter, created a demo app. just using stateless widget

```
void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text("Hello my app"),
          ),
          body: HelloRectangle()),
    );
  }
}

class HelloRectangle extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
    );
  }
}
```

But it shows the error :

```
Error -32601 received from application: Method not found
Reloaded 0 of 432 libraries in 525ms.
```

Is it always necessary name the class MyApp , as I could not run it if its name is changed.I am running flutter using VS CODE, and running "start debugging option"

Comment: have you tried a flutter clean?

Comment: thanks @RémiRousselet , looks like cache issue.